# PencilBlue - Custom Object Id's

Tags: node.js, mongodb, custom-object, pencilblue

I'm working with PencilBlue, and I'm having trouble with the custom objects Id's. The "name" field is used as an Id, but I would like it to be just a regular field and have an "id" field as identifier.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

PencilBlue cofounder here. Each custom object will have a unique id field supplied from the MongoDB database. You can also create another form field for a non-unique name and use the name field for UID.

Comment: Hi @Blake Callens, thanks for your answer. The problem we have is that the "name" field for a custom object is currently mandatory, and semantically, not all custom objects have a "name" property. E.g. in case of a Custom Object "Table", each object would have to have a "name" field, when it doesn't make much sense.

We found that using the name as UID, makes our clients confused in these cases.